# How do I use external python packages in this configuration

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework

I can not figure out how to import and/or use a python package. I really need some help getting off the ground with this. I want to accomplish getting 1 smoke test working. I'm now working in Windows 10 1809 os.

I've set up Eclipse to use Robotframework and RED robot. I have a project created with a folder, suite, and working test case (which does not include any Python). I've tried importing our "GoDirect" package, but when running the test shows that library has warning about no keywords. So, I'm assuming I have to create an external python.py file, and I tried to get one working but could not figure out how to set that up in the Eclipse Environment and use it.

My goal is to get a test case working that connects to a sensor, and reads information from it. I currently have no results other than a working skeleton test case. I'm new to Eclipse, but have "some" experience working with RobotFramework in the SikuliX IDE for a different application (using Mac Mojave).

This is my working Test case:

```
*** Settings ***   

Suite Setup       
Log    I am inside Test Suite Setup

Suite Teardown   
Log    I am inside Test suite Teardown

Test Setup       
Log    I am inside Test Setup

Test Teardown     
Log    I am insied Test Teardown   

Default Tags        sanity    

*** Test Cases ***

gdx_smoke_test

    [Tags]    smoke
    Log    Hello World...


*** Variables ***


*** Keywords ***
```

Below is a "pip list" of what I have installed on my Windows 10 1809 os:

Package                         Version

---

enum-compat                     0.0.2
godirect                        1.0.3
hidapi                          0.7.99.post21
pexpect                         4.7.0
pip                             19.1.1
ptyprocess                      0.6.0
pyserial                        3.4
robotframework                  3.1.1
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  3.3.1
selenium                        3.141.0
setuptools                      41.0.1
urllib3                         1.25.3
vernierpygatt                   3.2.0
wheel                           0.33.4

Below is the website we use for students and teachers to download and use our "godirect" python implementations

https://www.vernier.com/engineering/python/

05/30/2019 : I'm working on an external python file that creates a class object with a few "def" functions in it. I'm thinking I can put that .py someplace in the Eclipse project folder and import it (as a library) into RobotFramework. In theory I should be able to call Keywords into that .py class object. Example of the possible .py:

05/31/2019 : OK guys. I solved it on my own. I mislead myself a lot on our website. There was a few things I ended up doing to solve it. I'll explain below for anyone that's interested.

1) Copied gdx.py to site folder: It turns out I can't just do "pip install godirect[usb,ble]" alone. This only installs the site package in a folder that the Robotframework and RED.xml will use. I needed to also download one of their files that had a "gdx.py" file in it. That file has keywords in it such as "open_usb(self)" and many other ones. So I copied that "gdx.py" file to the site folder.

2) Add gdx.py to RED.xml : Double clicked the RED.xml which opens the RED project Referenced Libraries window. and added the gdx.py Library.

3) Added the "Library gdx" in the Settings of Robot Framework

4) Added keyword "open  usb": In my gdx_smoke_test I added this keyword to it

5) Ran the test suite and it passed!

The passing smoke test for using a custom Python file is below (shows changes I made to the original above)

```
*** Settings ***   
Library  gdx                       
Suite Setup       
Log    I am inside Test Suite Setup

Suite Teardown   
Log    I am inside Test suite Teardown

Test Setup       
Log    I am inside Test Setup

Test Teardown     
Log    I am insied Test Teardown   

Default Tags        sanity    

*** Test Cases ***

gdx_smoke_test

    [Tags]    smoke
    Log    Hello World...
    open . usb


*** Variables ***


*** Keywords ***
```

Comment: Our site shows to use, you would do this: from gdx import gdx
gdx = gdx.gdx(). I've gotten this to connect to the GoDirect hardware and collect data, but it was all done outside the context of the IDE (robotframework).

Comment: What library are you trying to import? Is it written by you?

Comment: Why do you think that your package is not imported? _I've tried importing but when running the test shows that library has warning about no keywords._ doesn't really sound like an import error. A typical module import error goes like `ImportError: No module named foo`

Comment: This code has several problems and is not a working test case. Have you read through the user guide? It has some very clear examples of how to create your own keyword libraries which can use any other modules you want.

Comment: Sameem: We have a GoDirect package that teachers and students can use to create Python scripts to connect our Go Direct Sensors. It's the "godirect" Library.

Comment: kerwei: The "godirect" Library does import. The point though is I don't know how to use it to create a Test Case that will let me connect to a Go Direct sensor. I will be experimenting with a GDX Temperature probe which I know works as I've done this outside the context of the IDE and configuration I'm using here.

Comment: Bryan Oakley: That test case I posted here does work for me. I can run it and get a passing Robotframework output. The problem I'm having here is I don't understand how to use our external package. I've written some Python scripts in the SikuliX project I did, but they were all "inline" functions I had made for Robotframework and SikuliX. What I'm doing now  is working on a Windows 10 system and have gone through a lot of videos from Automation Step by Step - Raghav Pal which helped me get this working in Eclipse with Robotframework. I'm gong to try and update this post with a "pip list".

Comment: Maybe I need to install "PyDev" but I'm not sure. If I did, will it still work with RobotFramework and/or is that the right approach here? Please see the "pip list" I added to the main body of this post. It shows what I'm installed so far and what versions are on the Windows 10 os.

Comment: Bryan Oakley: I edited that test case here to try and fix it correctly. It didn't paste in very well here, but it does run in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it myself. I made changes to the original post showing what I did to solve it.